# How to change Safari 6 Reader font?

Tags: safari

In Safari 5 you could just change the Reader.html file inside of the Safari.app to use a sans-serif font.
This Reader.html does not exist in Safari 6.

How do I manage to change the font of Safari Reader (6)?

I hate to read serif fonts.

Comment: One sure-working way is to delete the font Safari uses, and make a duplicate of the font you want named the same as what Safari uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a rule like this to `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Reader.html`:

```
.page, h1.title {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next' !important;
}
```

The `!important` is required because a `.page` div has an inline style attribute that overrides the fonts in `Reader.html`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! They moved it to a very obscure location.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the Reader.html CSS on iPad, iPhone or iPod, confirmed working on iOS8.1.2 iPad Air 2.

You will need to **Jailbreak your iOS device, and download a file system managing app called iFile**. Then you'll have full Explorer/Finder functionality on your iOS device.

Next, navigate to the folder:

> /var/stash/_.HVRQId/Applications/MobileSafari.app/Reader.html

This is the location on my iPad Air 2 with iOS 8.1.2, it may differ for you. If you upgrade to the paid version of iFile for $4, you can do a search system wide for the Reader.html file, which is what I did.

Open in Text Viewer, now just change the CSS as desired, anywhere you see the "font: -apple-system-*" declaration.

If you want to change the main body typography, **add a font-family declaration to the .page tag.** For example:

```
  .page {
        font: -apple-system-body;
        text-align: start;
        font-family: Georgia;
```

}

You can do the same thing to edit the **page heading under the h1.title tag**

```
h1.title {
        font: -apple-system-headline;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: start;
        -webkit-hyphens: manual;
        font-family: Georgia;
    }
```

Save Reader.html, reload the Safari webpage, and enjoy your new Reader font!